# How to open new winform from javascript call?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My main issue I am having with CEFSHARP currently is that I'm unable to figure out how to spawn a new windows form by using javascript within the cefsharp chromium browser control.

I tried searching on google for a solution but I couldn't find anything related to trying to spawn a new windows form when clicking a link/button in a page. Essentially talking back to the vb.net client from the javascript page.

From what I read I believe it's something related to a threading issue where the UI main thread of the main form isn't communicating to the javascript registered object correctly.

The code I have currently in VB (VS2015) is as follows:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser
    Friend Shared MyInstance As Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

        browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("/test.php") With {
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }

        webcontrol.Controls.Add(browser)

        browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("CallBrowser", New InteractAPP(), True)

    End Sub

    Public Sub SpawnForm()
        Dim myPop As New Form2
        myPop.Show()


    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MyInstance = Me

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class InteractAPP
    Public Sub showMessage()

        If (Form1.MyInstance IsNot Nothing) AndAlso Not Form1.MyInstance.IsDisposed Then
            MsgBox("It Works!")
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub createWin()
    form1.MyInstance.SpawnForm()

    End Sub

    Public Sub doHide()
        If (Form1.MyInstance IsNot Nothing) AndAlso Not Form1.MyInstance.IsDisposed Then
            Form1.MyInstance.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code that I have on my generic web page is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>

    // Setup communication to web browser control
    (async function() {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("CallBrowser", "bound");
    })();
    // calling ends here

    function doClose()
    {
        CallBrowser.doHide();
    }

    function openWindow()
    {

        //ByVal url As String, ByVal title As String, ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer, ByVal freeze As Integer, ByVal loadMaximize As Integer
        CallBrowser.createWin();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Close Win' onClick='doClose();'/>
<input type='button' value='Spawn Popup' onClick='openWindow();'/>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click Spawn Popup button on the webpage that refers to openWindow(), nothing happens when that function is called in VB.

I can't find any info anywhere on how to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is normal as all the actions your execute from your JavaScript via the CallBrowser object are run in a separate non UI thread. So, you where right when you said it was a threading issue.

To archive what you want you have to create a new window from your UI thread. You can use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods to run the code on the thread which owns the control you already have (instance of Form1 from your sample). Here is how your SpawnForm sub may look like:

```
Delegate Sub InvokeDelegate()

Public Sub SpawnForm()

    Me.BeginInvoke(New InvokeDelegate(
        Sub()
            Dim myPop As New Form2
            myPop.Show()
        End Sub
    ))

End Sub
```